# JavaCamera2View Change Preview Resolution

Tags: opencv, opencv3.0, android-camera2, android

Using OpenCV Android Tutorial I would like to change Preview Resolution. Therefore I commented out the calcPreviewSize function and set the resoultion to 640x480, which is supported and included in camera characteristics. The change of preview resolution is successful but often the app crashes although the given line does not contain any change from the official tutorial.

```
E/JavaCamera2View: createCaptureSession failed
               java.lang.IllegalStateException: Session has been closed; further changes are illegal.
                   at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraCaptureSessionImpl.checkNotClosed(CameraCaptureSessionImpl.java:607)
                   at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraCaptureSessionImpl.setRepeatingRequest(CameraCaptureSessionImpl.java:227)
                   at org.opencv.android.JavaCamera2View$3.onConfigured(JavaCamera2View.java:220)
                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
```

---

```
public class JavaCamera2View extends CameraBridgeViewBase {

private static final String LOGTAG = "JavaCamera2View";

private ImageReader mImageReader;
private int mPreviewFormat = ImageFormat.YUV_420_888;

public int widthP = 640;
public int heightP = 480;

public CameraDevice mCameraDevice;
private CameraCaptureSession mCaptureSession;
private CaptureRequest.Builder mPreviewRequestBuilder;
private String mCameraID;
private android.util.Size mPreviewSize = new android.util.Size(-1, -1);

private HandlerThread mBackgroundThread;
private Handler mBackgroundHandler;

public JavaCamera2View(Context context, int cameraId) {
    super(context, cameraId);
}

public JavaCamera2View(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

private void startBackgroundThread() {
    Log.i(LOGTAG, "startBackgroundThread");
    stopBackgroundThread();
    mBackgroundThread = new HandlerThread("OpenCVCameraBackground");
    mBackgroundThread.start();
    mBackgroundHandler = new Handler(mBackgroundThread.getLooper());
}

private void stopBackgroundThread() {
    Log.i(LOGTAG, "stopBackgroundThread");
    if (mBackgroundThread == null)
        return;
    mBackgroundThread.quitSafely();
    try {
        mBackgroundThread.join();
        mBackgroundThread = null;
        mBackgroundHandler = null;
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        Log.e(LOGTAG, "stopBackgroundThread", e);
    }
}

protected boolean initializeCamera() {
    Log.i(LOGTAG, "initializeCamera");
    CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
    try {
        String camList[] = manager.getCameraIdList();
        if (camList.length == 0) {
            Log.e(LOGTAG, "Error: camera isn't detected.");
            return false;
        }
        if (mCameraIndex == CameraBridgeViewBase.CAMERA_ID_ANY) {
            mCameraID = camList[0];
        } else {
            for (String cameraID : camList) {
                CameraCharacteristics characteristics = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraID);
                if ((mCameraIndex == CameraBridgeViewBase.CAMERA_ID_BACK &&
                        characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING) == CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING_BACK) ||
                    (mCameraIndex == CameraBridgeViewBase.CAMERA_ID_FRONT &&
                        characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING) == CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING_FRONT)
                ) {
                    mCameraID = cameraID;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if (mCameraID != null) {
            //CameraCharacteristics characteristics = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(mCameraID);
            //characteristics = manager.
            Log.i(LOGTAG, "Opening camera: " + mCameraID);
            manager.openCamera(mCameraID, mStateCallback, mBackgroundHandler);
        }
        return true;
    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        Log.e(LOGTAG, "OpenCamera - Camera Access Exception", e);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        Log.e(LOGTAG, "OpenCamera - Illegal Argument Exception", e);
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        Log.e(LOGTAG, "OpenCamera - Security Exception", e);
    }
    return false;
}

private final CameraDevice.StateCallback mStateCallback = new CameraDevice.StateCallback() {

    @Override
    public void onOpened(CameraDevice cameraDevice) {
        mCameraDevice = cameraDevice;
        createCameraPreviewSession();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisconnected(CameraDevice cameraDevice) {
        cameraDevice.close();
        mCameraDevice = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(CameraDevice cameraDevice, int error) {
        cameraDevice.close();
        mCameraDevice = null;
    }

};

private void createCameraPreviewSession() {
    final int w = widthP;//mPreviewSize.getWidth(), h = mPreviewSize.getHeight();
    final int h = heightP;
    Log.i(LOGTAG, "createCameraPreviewSession(" + w + "x" + h + ")");
    if (w < 0 || h < 0)
        return;
    try {
        if (null == mCameraDevice) {
            Log.e(LOGTAG, "createCameraPreviewSession: camera isn't opened");
            return;
        }
        if (null != mCaptureSession) {
            Log.e(LOGTAG, "createCameraPreviewSession: mCaptureSession is already started");
            return;
        }

        mImageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(w, h, mPreviewFormat, 2);
        mImageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener(new ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener() {
            @Override
            public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader) {
                Image image = reader.acquireLatestImage();
                if (image == null)
                    return;

                // sanity checks - 3 planes
                Image.Plane[] planes = image.getPlanes();
                assert (planes.length == 3);
                assert (image.getFormat() == mPreviewFormat);

                // see also https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ImageFormat.html#YUV_420_888
                // Y plane (0) non-interleaved => stride == 1; U/V plane interleaved => stride == 2
                assert (planes[0].getPixelStride() == 1);
                assert (planes[1].getPixelStride() == 2);
                assert (planes[2].getPixelStride() == 2);

                ByteBuffer y_plane = planes[0].getBuffer();
                ByteBuffer uv_plane = planes[1].getBuffer();
                Mat y_mat = new Mat(h, w, CvType.CV_8UC1, y_plane);
                Mat uv_mat = new Mat(h / 2, w / 2, CvType.CV_8UC2, uv_plane);
                JavaCamera2Frame tempFrame = new JavaCamera2Frame(y_mat, uv_mat, w, h);
                deliverAndDrawFrame(tempFrame);
                tempFrame.release();
                image.close();
            }
        }, mBackgroundHandler);
        Surface surface = mImageReader.getSurface();

        mPreviewRequestBuilder = mCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);
        mPreviewRequestBuilder.addTarget(surface);

        mCameraDevice.createCaptureSession(Arrays.asList(surface),
            new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onConfigured(CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                    Log.i(LOGTAG, "createCaptureSession::onConfigured");
                    if (null == mCameraDevice) {
                        return; // camera is already closed
                    }
                    mCaptureSession = cameraCaptureSession;
                    try {
                        mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE,
                                CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE_OFF);
                        mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE,
                                CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE_OFF);

                        mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_TARGET_FPS_RANGE, new Range<Integer>(30,30));

                        mCaptureSession.setRepeatingRequest(mPreviewRequestBuilder.build(), null, mBackgroundHandler);
                        Log.i(LOGTAG, "CameraPreviewSession has been started");
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.e(LOGTAG, "createCaptureSession failed", e);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onConfigureFailed(CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                    Log.e(LOGTAG, "createCameraPreviewSession failed");
                }
            },
            null
        );
    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        Log.e(LOGTAG, "createCameraPreviewSession", e);
    }
}

@Override
protected void disconnectCamera() {
    Log.i(LOGTAG, "closeCamera");
    try {
        CameraDevice c = mCameraDevice;
        mCameraDevice = null;
        if (null != mCaptureSession) {
            mCaptureSession.close();
            mCaptureSession = null;
        }
        if (null != c) {
            c.close();
        }
        if (null != mImageReader) {
            mImageReader.close();
            mImageReader = null;
        }
    } finally {
        stopBackgroundThread();
    }
}

boolean calcPreviewSize(final int width, final int height) {
    Log.i(LOGTAG, "calcPreviewSize: " + width + "x" + height);
    if (mCameraID == null) {
        Log.e(LOGTAG, "Camera isn't initialized!");
        return false;
    }
    CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
    try {
        CameraCharacteristics characteristics = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(mCameraID);
        StreamConfigurationMap map = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP);
        int bestWidth = 0, bestHeight = 0;
        float aspect = (float) width / height;
        android.util.Size[] sizes = map.getOutputSizes(ImageReader.class);
        bestWidth = sizes[0].getWidth();
        bestHeight = sizes[0].getHeight();
        for (android.util.Size sz : sizes) {
            int w = sz.getWidth(), h = sz.getHeight();
            Log.d(LOGTAG, "trying size: " + w + "x" + h);
            if (width >= w && height >= h && bestWidth <= w && bestHeight <= h
                    && Math.abs(aspect - (float) w / h) < 0.2) {
                bestWidth = w;
                bestHeight = h;
            }
        }
        Log.i(LOGTAG, "best size: " + bestWidth + "x" + bestHeight);
        assert(!(bestWidth == 0 || bestHeight == 0));
        if (mPreviewSize.getWidth() == bestWidth && mPreviewSize.getHeight() == bestHeight)
            return false;
        else {
            mPreviewSize = new android.util.Size(widthP, heightP);
            return true;
        }
    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        Log.e(LOGTAG, "calcPreviewSize - Camera Access Exception", e);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        Log.e(LOGTAG, "calcPreviewSize - Illegal Argument Exception", e);
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        Log.e(LOGTAG, "calcPreviewSize - Security Exception", e);
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
protected boolean connectCamera(int width, int height) {
    Log.i(LOGTAG, "setCameraPreviewSize(" + width + "x" + height + ")");
    startBackgroundThread();
    initializeCamera();
    try {
        boolean needReconfig = calcPreviewSize(width, height);
        mFrameWidth = mPreviewSize.getWidth();
        mFrameHeight = mPreviewSize.getHeight();

        if ((getLayoutParams().width == LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT) && (getLayoutParams().height == LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT))
            mScale = Math.min(((float)height)/mFrameHeight, ((float)width)/mFrameWidth);
        else
            mScale = 0;

        AllocateCache();

        if (needReconfig) {
            if (null != mCaptureSession) {
                Log.d(LOGTAG, "closing existing previewSession");
                mCaptureSession.close();
                mCaptureSession = null;
            }
            createCameraPreviewSession();
        }
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Interrupted while setCameraPreviewSize.", e);
    }
    return true;
}

private class JavaCamera2Frame implements CvCameraViewFrame {
    @Override
    public Mat gray() {
        return mYuvFrameData.submat(0, mHeight, 0, mWidth);
    }

    @Override
    public Mat rgba() {
        if (mPreviewFormat == ImageFormat.NV21)
            Imgproc.cvtColor(mYuvFrameData, mRgba, Imgproc.COLOR_YUV2RGBA_NV21, 4);
        else if (mPreviewFormat == ImageFormat.YV12)
            Imgproc.cvtColor(mYuvFrameData, mRgba, Imgproc.COLOR_YUV2RGB_I420, 4); // COLOR_YUV2RGBA_YV12 produces inverted colors
        else if (mPreviewFormat == ImageFormat.YUV_420_888) {
            assert (mUVFrameData != null);
            Imgproc.cvtColorTwoPlane(mYuvFrameData, mUVFrameData, mRgba, Imgproc.COLOR_YUV420sp2BGRA);
            // TODO: Here we had to change vom Imgproc.COLOR_YUV2RGBA_NV21 to Imgproc.COLOR_YUV420sp2BGRA to get the correct colors.
        } else
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Preview Format can be NV21 or YV12");

        return mRgba;
    }

    public JavaCamera2Frame(Mat Yuv420sp, int width, int height) {
        super();
        mWidth = width;
        mHeight = height;
        mYuvFrameData = Yuv420sp;
        mUVFrameData = null;
        mRgba = new Mat();
    }

    public JavaCamera2Frame(Mat Y, Mat UV, int width, int height) {
        super();
        mWidth = width;
        mHeight = height;
        mYuvFrameData = Y;
        mUVFrameData = UV;
        mRgba = new Mat();
    }

    public void release() {
        mRgba.release();
    }

    private Mat mYuvFrameData;
    private Mat mUVFrameData;
    private Mat mRgba;
    private int mWidth;
    private int mHeight;
};
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the face of it, there may be a problem with the modified `calcPreviewSize()` method: it may return **true** even if the preview size should not change.

You will see

```
I/JavaCamera2View best size: WWWWxHHH
```

in your logcat, where WWWW is not 640 and HHH is not 480.

Changing preview size involves close and reopen of **previewSession**, and takes time. The code that you use expects repeated calls to `calcPreviewSize()` to return **false**.

A possible fix is to rewrite the method this way:

```
boolean calcPreviewSize(final int width, final int height) {
    Log.i(LOGTAG, "calcPreviewSize: " + width + "x" + height);
    if (mCameraID == null) {
        Log.e(LOGTAG, "Camera isn't initialized!");
        return false;
    }
    if (mPreviewSize.getWidth() == widthP && mPreviewSize.getHeight() == heightP) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        mPreviewSize = new android.util.Size(widthP, heightP);
        return true;
    }
}
```